# List<dynamic> is not a realm model type

Tags: flutter, dart, realm

I was trying to generate new realm models in flutter. But it throws an error.

drillSession.dart

```
import 'package:realm/realm.dart';

import 'point.dart';

part 'drillSession.g.dart';

@RealmModel()
class _DrillSession {
  @MapTo('_id')
  @PrimaryKey()
  late ObjectId id;
  late List<Point> bulletCenters;
  late DateTime createdDate;
  @MapTo('owner_id')
  late String ownerId;
}
```

point.dart

```
import 'package:realm/realm.dart';

part 'point.g.dart';

@RealmModel()
class _Point {
  late int x;
  late int y;
}
```

But after the command,   `flutter pub run realm generate`

It displays the following error:

```
in: package:eagle/realm/drillSession.dart:12:8
    ╷
7   │ @RealmModel()
8   │ class _DrillSession {
    │       ━━━━━━━━━━━━━ in realm model for 'DrillSession'
... │
12  │   late List<Point> bulletCenters;
    │        ^^^^^^^^^^^ List<dynamic> is not a realm model type
    ╵
Remove the invalid field or add an @Ignored annotation on 'bulletCenters'.
```

Could you please let me know how can I resolve this error?

Comment: Is this just a typo? `_Point` vs `Point`?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
List<_Point>
```

Instead. You have to reference the realm model not the generated one.

Comment: Make point an embedded object

@RealmModel(ObjectType.embeddedObject)
class _Point {
  late int x;
  late int y;
}

Answer (score 0):

Make point an embedded object

```
@RealmModel(ObjectType.embeddedObject)
class _Point {
  late int x;
  late int y;
}
```

Refer ***Point*** class as ***_Point*** in your list

```
@RealmModel()
class _DrillSession {
  late List<_Point> bulletCenters;
}
```